# req.file is undefined while using multer for image upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I'm getting req.file undefined error while uploading an image using multer. I am sending my image from react to nodejs using FormData. I have looked almost every solution of Stack Overflow but I'm not able to fix the issue.

my React code for sending file:

```
const data = new FormData();
    data.append('profile',e.target.files[0]);
    axios.post('/imagefilter', data).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

input tag where I'm receiving the file:

```
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => { onChange(e) }} />
```

nodejs server code:

```
 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: (req,file,cb) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    cb(null,path.join(__dirname, './uploads'))
},
filename: (req,file,cb) => {
    cb(null,file.originalname);
}
```

})

post Route:

```
router.post(`/imagefilter`,upload.single('profile'),(req, res) => { console.log(req.file)})
```

I'm not able to figure out the error, I've wasted almost 24 hours fixing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was using

```
app.use(fileUpload())
```

before I was creating the imagefilter route, the issue resolved when I removed fileUpload()

Answer (score 1):

i think when you call api you need to add Content-Type": "multipart/form-data in header.

Comment: I tried using headers in axios but still req.file is undefined. And also, I am getting this error when I'm fetching the request using postman.